# $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] AND $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] Detection Issue

Tags: php, security, proxy

I have one website that generates a good traffic and i have found that other website is cloaking my website and i have problem on how to detect it with PHP so i can block it.

First of all
I have added `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or  `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to my code and when i access this cloaking websitethe result is right. It shows me the name of the website (cloakingwebsite.com) that is cloaking mywebsite.com

So i am now on cloakingwebsite.com (not my domain), with this code added on mywebsite.com (my domain)

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "cloakingwebsite.com" || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "cloakingwebsite.com"){
    echo "you are on cloakingwebsite.com";
}
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "mywebsite.com" || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "mywebsite.com"){
     echo "you are on mywebsite.com";
}
```

and i get **you are on mywebsite.com**

Conclusion:

If i use **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** or **$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']** with **echo** or **print** the result is right but if i use them with **if** and **else** statement the result is not right.

I don't know much about virtual or real ip and SERVER_NAME or HTTP_HOST but this looks like a security issue for me.

All my users that search for my website on google find this cloaking website and they login on my website trough this one because it is also managing cookies and everything.
As far as i know these websites may got all my users login info that goes trough them.
I have searched all the internet for a solution and that was javascript. 
I did that but now they got smart they filter and remove all javascript codes.

So the only option for me is **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** or **$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']** witch are not detected right.

I run PHP 7.1 on NGINX

Any solution please?

**myWebsite.com HEADERS**

```
[USER] => www-data
[HOME] => /var/www
[HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP] => 3a02:3f0e:5260:664:75fb:bb5a:f2a6:1ea3
[HTTP_COOKIE] => __cfduid=d7711ced6c319ac0aa615de5f64160b561509570260;
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6,ro;q=0.4
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
[HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
[HTTP_CF_VISITOR] => {"scheme":"https"}
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
[HTTP_CF_RAY] => 3b8d9bf459da7ea0-BUD
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 3a02:2f0e:3260:664:75fb:bb5a:f2a6:1ea3
[HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY] => RO
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
[HTTP_HOST] => mywebsite.com
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[SERVER_NAME] => mywebsite.com
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[SERVER_ADDR] => ******hiden.ip
[REMOTE_PORT] => 34741
[REMOTE_ADDR] => ****hiden.ip
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.13.6
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www
[DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 
[CONTENT_TYPE] => 
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/index.php
[FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1509882770.658
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1509882770
```

**cloakingWbsite.com HEADERS**

```
[USER] => www-data
[HOME] => /var/www
[HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP] => 3a01:3f8:171:2a4c:0:0:0:2
[HTTP_COOKIE] => __cfduid=dcad0dcc3004b494316f306212dc195911509878400;
[HTTP_REFERER] => 
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
[HTTP_CF_VISITOR] => {"scheme":"https"}
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
[HTTP_CF_RAY] => 3b8f5486a8196349-FRA
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 2a01:4f8:171:3a4c:0:0:0:2
[HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY] => DE
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
[HTTP_HOST] => proxywebsite.com
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[SERVER_NAME] => cloakingwebsite.com
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[SERVER_ADDR] => ***hidden.ip
[REMOTE_PORT] => 14485
[REMOTE_ADDR] => ***hidden.ip
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.13.6
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www
[DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 
[CONTENT_TYPE] => 
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/index.php
[FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1509879844.936
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1509879844
```

Comment: Niether `HTTP_HOST` nor `SERVER_NAME` will tell you anything about proxy usage. The `Host:` name is HTTP request field. Whereas `ServerName:` is a predefined name in your webservers virtual host section typically.

Comment: I don't understand how come when i echo the `SERVER_NAME` or `HTTP_HOST` it catches the right domain and both of them are equal with the proxysite.com domain, and if i use `SERVER_NAME` or `HTTP_HOST` in `if statement` are both equal with mydomain.com

Comment: You told me that  
Niether HTTP_HOST nor SERVER_NAME will tell me anything about proxy usage. It tells me if i use echo but in IF statement it does not tell me and i don't see the diference between echo and if. Why the SERVER_NAME is different in ECHO then in the IF statement?

Comment: None of what you've shown is plausible. `if` will not see values different from `print_r`. Apart from case-sensitivity issues, of course. The sample dumps you're showing here indicate a vhost alias you've set up yourself -- but conveniently forgot to mention. -- Long story short: that's not how **proxies** work. They act as cache between one website and another, and will act as regular HTTP client, sending the target webservers `Host:` field along. -- If you made up your mind, you can show your actual research rather than fictional examples here.

Answer (score 0):

If they truly are proxying your site, you need to determine the IP address of the server they're using and block them. If you block them from reaching your site, they can't act as a proxy.

So you should be looking at Apache, Nginx, or whatever web server you're running, inspect the log files, and look for tons of requests that come from the same IP, research this until you feel confident that it's them who is making those requests.

Then block them at the firewall level, or by using a service such as CloudFlare. Note that using a service like CloudFlare would help you avoid this sort of trouble to begin with, because they will be capable of monitoring inhuman amounts of traffic for you. Their service is free. https://www.cloudflare.com/security/

Comment: I already run cloudflare and the proxy website runs cloudflare: Cloud flare has alot of ips

Comment: headers are most exactly as my website headers. The only difference is ip and server_name and HTTP_HOST. Ips are different everytime

Comment: @MihaiGalan Good, so if you're on CloudFlare I suggest setting a rate limit so that a single site is then unable to proxy requests from their site to many others. See: https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limiting/

Comment: Under: CloudFlare Account → Firewall (Tab) → Rate Limiting

Comment: This don't sound like a good solution: First 10,000 requests are free.
$0.05 per 10,000 legitimate (non-blocked) requests thereafte