# How can i block all CloudFlare IPs in PHP

Tags: php, block, cloudflare

I have a problem with some proxy sites that are using cloudflare and they are  cloaking and spamdexing my website.

How can i block all cloudflare ip's in php so these sites that are scraping my website get blocked .. or is there any better solution?
My website is also using cloudflare.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ?

Comment: yes X and Y ... what?

Comment: @MihaiGalan He means you need to explain the underlying problem in more detail, not the solution you currently have in mind.

Comment: @MihaiGalan https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The solution i have in mind is to block all cloudflare ips from connecting to my website. so i found CloudFlare ip range list https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/ but i don't know how to block them all. This is the solution i am think about. If is there other solution that would help me block CloudFlare websites to connecting my websites i am open to that also

Comment: @MihaiGalan No, what is the **underlying problem**? Your proposed solution is very unusual and I'm mystified as to why you're asking about it. We need to know what's actually going on and how it's causing a problem. You need to add more detail to your question about what is happening and how it's affecting your site.

Comment: There are these proxysites that looks exactly like mine. they scrap contents from my website i want to block them. I cannot detect them using $_SERVER['http_host']. These sites uses cloudflare. The only way i can block them is by IP. CloudFlare ip is changeing every time.

Comment: First: check your logfiles. The scrapers don't necessarily need to be on the same hosts as the copycats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

luckily, cloudflare provides a list of their IP ranges [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/), so just check if the connecting IP is within 1 of those ranges, and exit() if it is.

example implementation using the [M6Web/Firewall](https://github.com/M6Web/Firewall/tree/master):

```
use M6Web\Component\Firewall\Firewall;

if(!((new Firewall())->setDefaultState(true)->addList(file('blacklist.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES),'localBad')->setIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->handle())){
     http_response_code(403);
     exit();
}
```

with an accompanying daily cronjob:

```
<?php
$ips = file_get_contents ( 'https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4' ) . "\n" . file_get_contents ( 'https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6' );
file_put_contents ( '/path/to/blacklist.txt', $ips );
```

- note that it would be difficult to implement ipv6 cidr ranges manually, thus you should probably use a 3rd-party libary, like the M6Web firewall. also, it would be much more performant to do it with iptables than at the php level.
- the cronjob is not really required, you can fetch a fresh list of ips with every pageload, but that would probably be very slow, and, perhaps ironically, you'd might get auto ip-banned from cloudflare.com for spamming, thus i highly suggest you use a daily cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i block all cloudflare ip's
>
> My website is also using cloudflare

You cannot - otherwise you will not be able to use cloudflare yourself.

A better solution would be to have your webserver (eg. apache or nginx) check the host header (which is what the user sees in the address bar) and if it's something other than your normal domain just 301 redirect (permanent) - this will tell search engines that the content has "moved" from scrapping site to legitimate site

Comment: I have made a post before where you have more detail info about this issue i have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121098/serverhttp-host-and-serverserver-name-detection-issue/47121149

Answer (score 0):

I use a firewall rule to block all Cloudflare ip ranges. Works great, no problems so far.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).